# Disabling completions on Google Japanese Input romaji mode

Tags: google-japanese-input

I'd like to use the latin mode of Google Japanese Input to type English, so that I don't have to switch keyboard between languages, but only switch the mode using the あ/A key.

But the latin / romaji mode has the same completion menu as the あ mode, which is completely useless in English and requires an additional Enter keypress to make the app see the entered text.

Is there a way to disable the completion functionality for the latin mode?

Comment: A screenshot might help those that don't use the keyboard, to understand exactly what you mean.